# Send email outlook SMTP .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, smtp

I am using following code send email through SMTP outlook.

```
public class EmailHelper
{
    private static string SmtpServer { get; set; }
    private static int SmtpPort { get; set; }
    private static string SmtpUser { get; set; }
    private static string SmtpPassword { get; set; }

    public EmailHelper()
    {
        SmtpServer = "smtp.office365.com";
        SmtpPort = 587;
        SmtpUser = "********"; //Organization email
        SmtpPassword = "******";//password
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// SendEmail
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="emailInfo"></param>
    public void SendEmail(EmailInfo emailInfo)
    {
        emailInfo.SmtpServer = SmtpServer;
        emailInfo.SmtpPort = SmtpPort;
        emailInfo.SmtpUser = SmtpUser;
        emailInfo.SmtpPassword = SmtpPassword;

        using (var client = new SmtpClient(emailInfo.SmtpServer, emailInfo.SmtpPort))
        {
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailInfo.SmtpUser, emailInfo.SmtpPassword);
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage
            {
                From = new MailAddress(emailInfo.From),
                Subject = emailInfo.Subject,
                Body = emailInfo.Body,
                IsBodyHtml = emailInfo.IsBodyHtml
            };

            foreach (var to in emailInfo.To)
            {
                mailMessage.To.Add(to);
            }

            client.Send(mailMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

I am always getting the error "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond" or the "operation timeout"

Please help to sort out this issue

Comment: Make sure your server is actually allowed to call out. You haven't provided a ton of information, but it's quite typical to disable outside network access on servers in enterprise environments.

Comment: Share us the value for `emailInfo`. Can you send email from your current developer pc manually?

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that the settings cannot be configured correctly using the SmtpClient object.  To send email with office 365 you need SSL off and TLS on which isn't correctly set using the SmtpClient.EnableSSL setting.

Try this:

```
var server = new SmtpServer("smtp.office365.com");

server.User = "********";
server.Password = "********";

// Set 587 port
server.Port = 587;

// detect SSL/TLS connection automatically
server.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;

// create mail instance
var mail = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
mail.To = "to@email.com";
mail.Subject = "subject";
mail.TextBody = "text body";

// send
smtp.SendMail(server, mail);
```

**I didn't run this but it should be close**

Comment: Did you use "EASendMail" dependency?

Comment: I'm sending email in production through O365 with just `EnableSSL` on. Works fine. What you're doing here isn't necessary.

Comment: I am using  client.EnableSsl = true;

Comment: @ChrisPratt Well if that is the case then I am wrong and there must be another issue with his code or settings.  The other likely cause would be simply lack of connection but I didn't think it would be that obvious.